# Disable showing key when key pressed in LowLevel Hook

Tags: visual-c++, low-level, keyboard-hook

I'm trying to learn about Low Level Hook. I want to change the input of users. Stuff like this, when user press a and then w, the ouput is ă. My solution is:

- After user type w, i will use sendInput to send 2 backspace keys and a unicode character ă.

The problem is: it will show the w character on screen before it delete by backspace and I don't want that. Is there any solution to hide w character when user type it?

Example: This is what happend in the screen

What was happen:  a  ->  aw  ->  a  ->  -> ă

I want: a -> ă

This is my HookProcedure

```
    LRESULT CALLBACK InternalKeyboardHookCallback(int code, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam){

    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *pKeyboardStruct = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *)lparam;
    if(wparam == WM_KEYUP){
        if(pKeyboardStruct->vkCode==0x41){
            state = true;
        }
        if((pKeyboardStruct->vkCode==0x57)&&(state)){
            SendInput(0x08);
            SendInput(0x08);
            SendInputUnicode(0x0103);
            state = false;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hookKeyboard, code, wparam, lparam);
}
```

This is SendInput and SendInputUnicode

```
    void SendInputUnicode(int wScan){
    INPUT input[2];
    memset(input, 0, sizeof(input));
    input[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    //Input UNICODE
    input[0].ki.wVk = 0; // VK_PACKET
    input[0].ki.dwFlags = 4;//Send Unicode
    input[0].ki.wScan = wScan;
    input[0].ki.time = 0;
    input[0].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    input[1].ki.wVk = 0; // VK_PACKET
    input[1].ki.wScan = wScan;
    input[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP|4;
    input[1].ki.time = 0;
    input[1].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    SendInput(2,input,sizeof(INPUT));
}

void SendInput(int wScan){
    INPUT input[2];
    memset(input, 0, sizeof(input));
    input[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    //Input UNICODE
    input[0].ki.wVk = wScan; // VK_PACKET
    input[0].ki.dwFlags = 0;//Send Unicode
    input[0].ki.wScan = 0;
    input[0].ki.time = 0;
    input[0].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    input[1].ki.wVk = wScan; // VK_PACKET
    input[1].ki.wScan = 0;
    input[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    input[1].ki.time = 0;
    input[1].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    SendInput(2,input,sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

Comment: I solved it :)).
To prevent w character appearing. Just return 1 when wparam = WM_KEYDOWN. Here is the code after I fix.

Comment: If you only need to replace certain keys, it would make a lot more sense to use the `RegisterHotKey` function instead.